# ReactJS: input is not editable

Tags: reactjs, input, readonly

I am creating a study "Laravel-ReactJS" application where I have a form in a component. The problem is that what ever I do the state is not getting updated.

However I have tried this same code in a standalone React application (without laravel) and the code worked without any issue.

**Here is my code:**

```
constructor()
{
  super();

  this.state = {
    title: ''
  };
}

onSetTitle(event)
{
  console.log(event.target.title);

  this.setState({
    title: event.target.title
  });

  console.log(this.state.title);
}

render (
  return (
    <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group">
      <label>Name<em>*</em></label>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        name="title" 
        id="title" 
        className="form-control" 
        onChange={this.onSetTitle.bind(this)} 
        value={this.state.title}
      />
    </div>
  )
)
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

I am following this youtube tutorial https://youtu.be/aDpoKnBlCCM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the `value` of a *syntetic event*, you should access it through `event.target.value`

*event.target.title* will always be `undefined`

That’s the reason why your input’s value isn’t updating.

You should do instead:

```
onSetTitle(event)
{

  this.setState({
    title: event.target.value
  });

}
```

———————————

[Syntetic events work just like native HTML events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

Comment: Man, so that's the reason why it was not working. My entire day is ruined because of this issue. Many thanks @victor.ja. **It worked**

Comment: Glad to help @Pummi  ! The most simple bugs are the hardest to fix 

Comment: could you please have a look on these 2 questions as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54838816/reactjs-404-error-on-reloading-the-inner-components-in-dev-env and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832801/reactjs-including-script-in-a-specific-component

Answer (score 1):

The value of the input will be present in the `value` property of `event.target`, not `title`.

```
onSetTitle(event) {
  this.setState({
    title: event.target.value
  });
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      title: ""
    };
  }

  onSetTitle(event) {
    this.setState({
      title: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-group">
        <label>
          Name<em>*</em>
        </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          id="title"
          className="form-control"
          onChange={this.onSetTitle.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.title}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```